# how can i send a value onclick on a image in javascript to get a value in to a text field

Tags: php, javascript

i want to get a value from `database` coresponding to this `image` `onclick`.
but this function is not working i can't define value in img tag then how can i send this value to my function.

please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choose(x)
    {
    document.getElementById('color').value=x;
    }
</script>
<img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $data['image'];?>" value="<?php echo $data['color'];?>"
width="25" height="25" onclick="choose(this.value);"/>
```

Comment: you  are not closing the  script tag

Comment: can you please accept the solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function choose(x)
{
document.getElementById('color').value=x;
}
</script>
<img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $data['image'];?>" title="<?php echo $data['color'];?>" width="25" height="25" onclick="choose(this.title);"/>
```

Just change the attribute `value` to `title` and `onclick="choose(this.title)"`

Comment: there is no need of using title attribute for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $data['image'];?>"
width="25" height="25" onclick="choose('<?php echo $data['color'];?>');"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must create a ajax function to get a value from database like this

```
 function choose(x)
 {
    $.ajax({
         'type': 'get',
         'url': 'getDataValue.php',
         'data': 'color='+x,

         success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('color').value=data;
         },
         error: function(data){
             alert("Ajax error occured");
         }


   });
}
```

Using ajax function you may fetch data from a table  in getDataValue.php file. In getDataValue.php file you must run a query that get result from database table.

Thanks

Comment: -1 I don't see the need of using separate request on each function call